# Find possible values in perfect square problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $P+45$ and $P+136$ are two **perfect squares**, Then **how many possible values of $P$ may exist?
Given that $P$ is an **integer**

Comment: It is not allowed to add both the number-theory and elementary-number-theory tags on the same question. The description of the number-theory tag explains it: "Questions on more advanced topics of number theory. ". The number-theory tag has to be removed from this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $P+45=m^2, P+136=n^2$  Subtract these and factor.

Answer (score 1):

The difference $(P+136)-(P+45)=91=13\cdot 7$ is $m^2-n^2=(m+n)(m-n)$. Now there are two possibilities: $m+n=13$ and $m+n=91$. Can you finish now?

Comment: Remember that $m,n$ can be negative as well, which means you can't just deduce that $m+n\ge 13$. If $(m,n)$ is a solution, so is $(m,-n)$.

Comment: @mathh But you're solving for $P$.  Both $(m,n)$ and $(m,-n)$ yield the same value of $P$.

Comment: @Mike I am talking about the equation $(m+n)(m-n)=91$. ajotatxe seems to have assumed that $m+n>m-n$, which is not always true, e.g., when $m$ is positive and $n$ is negative.

Comment: I generally think you have assumed that $m,n\in\mathbb N$, but in fact it is $m,n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: n and -n give the same value of P. As the question is on values of P, we can probably ignore negative n's